# Count multiple column matches (Ex: first & last name) across multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In need to count the occurrences of names (COL1 + COL2) in multiple sheets.

Sample data structure:

```
  {Sheet1}          {Sheet2}          {Sheet3}
-------------     -------------     -------------
COL1  COL2        COL1  COL2        COL1  COL2
----  ----        ----  ----        ----  ----   
Jim   Smith       Jim   Smith       Burt  Malone
Dana  Brown       Jill  White       Jim   Smith
Jane  Doe         Dana  Brown       Dana  Brown
Jane  Johnson     Angie Wild        Jill  White
Burt  Malone      Tim   Peterson
```

Expected result:

```
NAME        COUNT
----------  ----- 
Angie Wild    1
Burt Malone   2
Dana Brown    3
Jane Doe      1
Jane Johnson  1
Jill White    2
Jim Smith     2
Tim Peterson  1
```

Answer (score 0):

A unique key would be useful, not only in answering your immediate issue but quite likely in avoiding others. Merely concatenating the two columns would provide that (for your sample data, not necessarily otherwise, so I would recommend a more robust index system). With such a key, say in ColumnI for each sheet, a formula such as below may serve:

```
=query({Sheet1!I1:I11;Sheet2!I1:I11;Sheet3!I1:I11},"SELECT Col1, count(Col1) WHERE Col1 IS NOT null group by Col1")
```

The above requires a term of this kind:`Sheet3!I1:I11` for each sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample script to do the same:

```
//@OnlyCurrentDoc
function countUnique() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); //get All Sheets
  var input = {},output=[];
  for (var i in sheets){ //Loop through all sheets for A:B column values
    var values = sheets[i].getRange("A1:B"+sheets[i].getLastRow()).getValues();
    values.forEach(function(e){
      var a = (e[0]+' '+e[1]).trim(); // create unique property name with A&B
      if (a){
        input[a] = input[a]+1 || 1; //increment count of  name for each occurence    
      }
    });
    //Logger.log(input);
  }
  var output = Object.keys(input).map(function(e){return [e,input[e]]}); //Convert it back to array     
  //Logger.log(output);
  sheets[0].getRange(sheets[0].getLastRow()+1,1, output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output); //set the output values to Sheet1 Last Row    
}
```